# Javascript Validation not working in C# (Error message)

Tags: javascript, c#

Here is the javascript validation code:

```
if (document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").value.trim() == "") {
document.getElementById("<%=dvMessage.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "Please enter Category.";

document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").focus();

document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").classList.add("ErrorControl");
// document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").style.outline = '1px solid red';
// document.getElmentById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").style.border = '3px solid red';
return false;

}
if (document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>").value.trim() == "") {
document.getElementById("<%=dvMsg.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "Please enter Category Description.";
document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>").focus();
document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>").classList.add("ErrorControl");
// document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>").style.outline = '1px solid red';
return false;
}
}

<script>
function checkfunction(val) {
if (val != "") {

document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>").classList.remove("ErrorControl");
// document.getElementById("<%=dvMessage.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>").classList.remove("ErrorControl");
// document.getElementById("<%=dvMsg.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';
}
}
</script>
```

Here is the text box:

```
<div class="field">
<div id="dvMessage" runat="server" style="color: Red" >
</div>
<label>
Category Name <em>*</em>
</label>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryName" runat="server" CssClass="form-01-control" onkeyup="checkfunction(this.value)" placeholder="Enter Category Name" ></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div id="dvMsg" runat="server" style="color: Red">
</div>
<label>
Category Description <em>*</em></label>
<div>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCategoryDescription" runat="server" CssClass="form-01-control" onkeyup="checkfunction(this.value)" placeholder="Enter Category Description"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
<label>
Parent Category </label>
<div>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlParentCategory" runat="server" Width="250px" class="form-01-control">
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<label>
Category Image</label>
<div>
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuImage" runat="server" />
<asp:Image ID="imgCategory" Width="100" Height="100" runat="server" />
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that validation not working properly. The ERROR MESSAGE shows I'm having a problem. Please tell me what to do for multiple textbox and dropdown and how to use javascript validation?

Comment: Is checkfunction(val) receiving the correct values? As a sidenote, you can cache DOM elements in a var, you don't have to getElementById the same element 4 times in a row.

Comment: How????can you describe me?yes red color comes on textbox border by css class in ErrorControl but problem in error message

Comment: here you just tell me how to hide and show error message respectively

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, sorry. What I can make from this code is that when the user types into one of the two textboxes, both textboxes will get the css class ErrorControl removed from them.

Comment: Sir i want simple validation using javascript  just like above ...can you post a answer????

Comment: You can simple use JQuery ValidationEngine to accomplish validation here.

Comment: I'll give it a try, but one last question. Those elements: Are you setting and removing the class ErrorControl from the the divs underneath the textboxes, or are you changing the class on the textboxes itsself. Since the id is sent by the server, we don't know if you're updating the divs or the textboxes.

Comment: sir here i am using function checkfunction(val) function for when textbox having null values then it will show me a red color border...

Comment: no my requirement is javascript validation only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, is something like this what you need? And as Abhay said, there's a load of plugins you can use, jquery is just a javascript library.

```
<script>
var catName = {
        'label' : document.getElementById("<%=dvMessage.ClientID %>"),
        'textbox' : document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryName.ClientID %>")
    },
    catDesc = {
        'label' : document.getElementById("<%=dvMsg.ClientID %>"),
        'textbox' : document.getElementById("<%=txtCategoryDescription.ClientID %>")    
    },
    noText = function hasText( textbox ) {
        return textbox.value.trim().length === 0;
    };
// This entire part might be redundant, unless the textbox comes back from the server with text already inside it.
// If the textbox is always empty at startup, this part could be replaced by placing the text already into the div.
if (noText(catName.textbox)) {
    catName.label.innerHTML = "Please enter Category.";
    catName.textbox.focus()
    catName.textbox.classList.add("ErrorControl");
}
if (noText(catDesc.textbox)) {
    catDesc.label.innerHTML = "Please enter Category Description.";
    catDesc.textbox.focus()
    catDesc.textbox.classList.add("ErrorControl");
}

function checkfunction( textValue ) {
    var catNameCls = catName.textbox.classList,
        catDescCls = catDesc.textbox.classList;
    if (textValue.length !== 0) {
        if (catNameCls.contains("ErrorControl")) catNameCls.remove("ErrorControl");
        else catNameCls.add("ErrorControl");
        if (catDescCls.contains("ErrorControl")) catDescCls.remove("ErrorControl");
        else catDescCls.add("ErrorControl");        
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: if ($("#txtQEditor iframe").contents().find("body").val == "") {
                $("#txtQEditor iframe").contents().innerHTML = "Please enter Email Body .";
                document.getElementById("<%=dvEmlMsg.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "Please enter Email Body .";
                document.getElementById("<%=dvEmlMsg.ClientID %>").style.display = 'block';
                $("#txtQEditor iframe").contents().find("body").focus();
                document.getElementById("<%=txtQEditor.ClientID %>").classList.add("ErrorControl");
                return false;
            }

Comment: What isn't working? My code or the code you just posted? The code you just posted uses iframes and suddenly has JQuery, so I guess this is a different question? Please update your original question and tell us what error the console gives. With 'Not working' we don't know anything.